# Python: cx_Freeze .exe doesn't work & .py file works fine

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, exe, cx-freeze

I've been working on this little tool to analyse our ticketdatabase.

[image: my GUI]

The main goal is 1. to choose a pickle file, which consists of many dictionaries which look like this:

```
2458 {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Kunde', 
'ticket-closed': True, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 77779, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 77779, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 15, 12, 53, 29570, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}



2459 {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Kunde', 
'ticket-closed': True, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 94126, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'W\xfcnschenswert')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 94126, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 14, 47, 28, 916677, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}
```

2. seperate the data in different dictionaries (created, closed, open)
3. to use matplotlib to show my data in a piechart.

[image: mpl_figure]

As you can see everything works fine till here. After that I've wanted to create an .exe so I can use my tool on other computers, too.

I've managed to create an .exe with cx_Freeze. It runs flawlessly but i dont get any useful results and I dont know what I've done wrong.

[image: figure_2]

This is what my setup.py looks like:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
import pickle
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("ticketanalysis.py", base=base, icon = "Iconka-Saint-Whiskers-Cat-cupid-love.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Ticketauswertung CX_FREEZE",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"packages":["Tkinter","matplotlib", "numpy", "PIL", "os", "pickle", "datetime", "xlwt", "tkFileDialog"], "include_files":["Iconka-Saint-Whiskers-Cat-cupid-love.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Ticketanalysissoftware by KH",
    executables = executables
    )
```

And this is my code:

```
import pickle
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

datanameString = ''
datapathString = ''
ClosedDict = {}
OpenDict = {}
CreatedDict = {}
ClosedList = [0] * 53
OpenList = [0] * 53
CreatedList = [0] * 53

################################################################################
#Methods

def getDataname():    
    global datanameString
    global CreatedList
    global OpenList
    global ClosedList
    global datapathString

    CreatedList = [0] * 53
    OpenList = [0] * 53
    ClosedList = [0] * 53
    ClosedDict.clear()
    OpenDict.clear()
    CreatedDict.clear()

    datapathString = askopenfilename()
    datanameString = os.path.basename(datapathString)

    l3 = Label(root, text='').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    l3 = Label(root, text=datanameString).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

    print "FILENAME CHOSEN!"

def SeperateData(pickle_filename):
    freshpickle = pickle.load(open(pickle_filename, 'rb'))

    ClosedDict.clear()
    OpenDict.clear()
    CreatedDict.clear()

    for (i,j) in freshpickle.iteritems():
        if j['ticket-closed'] == True:
            ClosedDict[i] = j
            CreatedDict[i] = j

    for (i,j) in freshpickle.iteritems():
        if j['ticket-closed'] == False:
            OpenDict[i] = j
            CreatedDict[i] = j

    print "SEPERATING DATA FINISHED!"

def ShowPieChart():
    internCounter = 0
    kundeCounter = 0
    newCounter = 0
    closedCounter = 0
    developingCounter = 0
    testingCounter = 0
    tbdCounter = 0
    HWCounter = 0
    SWCounter = 0
    tClosedCounter = 0
    tOpenCounter = 0

    for (i,j) in CreatedDict.iteritems():
        if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'new':
            newCounter += 1
        if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'closed':
            closedCounter += 1
        if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'developing':
            developingCounter += 1
        if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'testing':
            testingCounter += 1
        if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'tbd':
            tbdCounter += 1

    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    fig = plt.figure()

    labels = ('new', 'closed', 'developing', 'testing', 'tbd')
    sizes = [newCounter, closedCounter, developingCounter, testingCounter, tbdCounter]
    colors = ['#F5FC34', '#52FC34', '#FAAB23', '#237DFA', '#C863FA', ]
    explode = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
    ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax1.set_title("Anforderungen: Status")

    for (i,j) in CreatedDict.iteritems():
        if j['department'] == 'Intern':
            internCounter += 1
        if j['department'] == 'Kunde':
            kundeCounter += 1

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)            
    labels = ('Intern', 'Kunde')
    sizes = [internCounter, kundeCounter]
    colors = ['#FAF063', '#63BBFA']
    explode = (0, 0) 
    ax2.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax2.set_title("Anforderungen: Department")

    for (i,j) in CreatedDict.iteritems():
        if j['origin'] == 'HW':
            HWCounter += 1
        if j['origin'] == 'SW':
            SWCounter += 1

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)            
    labels = ('HW', 'SW')
    sizes = [HWCounter, SWCounter]
    colors = ['#6A0D7D', '#503C3C']
    explode = (0, 0) 
    ax2.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax2.set_title("Anforderungen: Origin")

    for (i,j) in CreatedDict.iteritems():
        if j['ticket-closed'] == True:
            tClosedCounter += 1
        if j['ticket-closed'] == False:
            tOpenCounter += 1

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)            
    labels = ('Closed', 'Open')
    sizes = [tClosedCounter, tOpenCounter]
    colors = ['#58FB4C', '#F8183A']
    explode = (0, 0) 
    ax2.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax2.set_title("Anforderungen: Closed-Status")

    figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    figManager.window.showMaximized()
    plt.show()

################################################################################
#GUI

root = Tk() 
root.title("Ticketanalysis v1.0")
root.geometry("350x340")


l1 = Label(root, text="Ticketanalysis by KH\n", width=50).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
l2 = Label(root, text="", width=50).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
b1 = Button(root, text='Choose File', command = getDataname, width=50).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
b2 = Button(root, text='Seperate Data', command = lambda: SeperateData(datapathString), width=50).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
b7 = Button(root, text='ShowPieChart', command = ShowPieChart, width=50).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

mainloop()    

################################################################################
```

I know that my code is not perfect but I am only asking you to help me get that .exe working properly.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need just to run your app, rename file extension to pyw.

Comment: it only works for me if the file is in the python folder.